# expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled() fails even though the React component method is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am attempting to test whether a React component method is called using enzyme and jest. The function is supposed to be called when a `<section>` element becomes unfocused (on blur). The component is connected to a Redux store, but it is also exported by name, to take Redux out of the equation. Below is a simplified version of the component:

```
export class Section extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.formRef = React.createRef();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      formSubmitted: false
    }
  }

  submitForm() {
    console.log("form submitted");
    this.setState({ formSubmitted: true })
    if (this.formRef && this.formRef.current) {
      this.formRef.current.submit();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section onBlur={this.submitForm}>
        <form ref={this.formRef} action={url} method='post'>
          <input type="text" name="something" />
        </form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Section);
```

I have tried all kinds of combinations for the `spyOn` portion, since it seems to be the root of the issue. All have failed.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Section } from './Section';

describe('Section', () => {
  it('should submit form on blur', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Section content={{ body: [] }} />);
    const spy = spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitForm');
    const spy2 = spyOn(Section.prototype, 'submitForm');
    const spy3 = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitForm');
    const spy4 = jest.spyOn(Section.prototype, 'submitForm');

    wrapper.find('section').simulate('blur');
    expect(wrapper.state().formSubmitted).toEqual(true);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy3).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy4).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })
})
```

I gave the component a state and tested it in addition to testing `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled` in order to verify whether the function was actually called, and it seems to be the case.

The `console.log('form submitted')` appears in the console.

The test `expect(wrapper.state().formSubmitted).toEqual(true);` passes, which indicates to me that the correct function is being called. However, I don't want to have an unnecessary state just for the test. The state has just been added to assert that "submitForm" method is being called.

The assertions `expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled()` all fail with error `Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called` or `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting, this question dives right into some of the more unusual aspects of JavaScript.

---

### What happens

`submitForm` is originally defined as a [prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods):

```
class Section extends React.Component {
  ...
  submitForm() { ... }
  ...
}
```

...meaning you would create the `spy` like this:

```
jest.spyOn(Section.prototype, 'submitForm');
```

...but then it gets redefined as an [instance property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Instance_properties) within the `constructor`:

```
this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
```

...meaning you would **now** create the `spy` like this:

```
jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitForm');
```

...but that **still** doesn't work because `onBlur` gets bound **directly** to `this.submitForm` during the `render`:

```
<section onBlur={this.submitForm}>
```

So the way the code is currently written actually makes it impossible to spy on `submitForm` because creating the `spy` requires an `instance` but the `instance` isn't available until the component has rendered and `onBlur` gets bound directly to `this.submitForm` during rendering.

---

### Solution

Change `onBlur` to be *a function that calls `this.submitForm`* so that whenever `onBlur` fires it will call the *current value* of `this.submitForm`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <section onBlur={() => this.submitForm()}>
      <form ref={this.formRef} action={url} method='post'>
        <input type="text" name="something" />
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```

...then when you replace `submitForm` with the `spy` on the `instance` the `spy` will get called when `onBlur` fires:

```
describe('Section', () => {
  it('should submit form on blur', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Section content={{ body: [] }} />);
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'submitForm');

    wrapper.find('section').simulate('blur');
    expect(wrapper.state().formSubmitted).toEqual(true);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  })
})
```

Comment: Creating an arrow function on every render may cause performance issues.

Comment: @AndreiDotsenko according to the official `React` doc: **Is it OK to use arrow functions in render methods?** ["Generally speaking, yes, it is OK"](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#is-it-ok-to-use-arrow-functions-in-render-methods).  If you have performance issues then by all means remove the arrow function, but the performance cost is typically very small.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you want to verify if form's `submit()` is called when `Section` loses focus, right? So you don't need to verify if internal method has been called - it would not ensure if form is submitted or not. Also it would lead to false-negative results in case of refactoring(internal method is renamed and everything works but test fails).

You can mock ref object instead. Then you will be able to verify if form has been submitted

```
it('should submit form on blur', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Section content={{ body: [] }} />);
  wrapper.instance().formRef.current = { submit: jest.fn()};
  wrapper.find('section').simulate('blur');
  expect(wrapper.instance().formRef.current.submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Sure test also relies on component's internals(onto property that contains ref). But this way I believe test is more... say reliable.